# Python SQlite FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:'x.txt'

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm somehow running into a problem that should not be a problem (in my eyes).

I'm trying to call a .txt file that is in the same directory as the .py file that calls for opening the .txt file but still get this message. I tried the os.chdir method and the terminal is in the precise folder I want to fetch the .txt file from as well. All doesn't work.

I tried to look for solutions here but couldn't find any. Here is the code:

```
import sqlite3
#import os

conn = sqlite3.connect('db_2.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Counts')

cur.execute('''
CREATE TABLE Counts (email
TEXT, count INTEGER)''')

#os.chdir(r'c:\I\put\the\right\directory\here\')

fname = input('Enter file name: ',)
fh = open(fname)
print(fh)
```

This is the full error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "c:/Users/John/Desktop/Career/Python/Python 4
>   everybody/Ex_c4_wk2_db_2/Ex_c4_wk2_db_2.py", line 16, in 
>       fh = open(fname) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mbox.txt'

I # out the os.chdir method for now, it should be working without, no?
What might be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you type as input when you're prompted to? The error seems to suggest you type 'x' as filename...

Comment: Oh, sorry, I input the filename plus extension: "mbox.txt".

Comment: Can you post the full error traceback in your question?

Comment: Done, thanks for your patience :)

Comment: Can you add the line `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` to your script (before the `input` call) and check that the folder is the correct one containing the file you're trying to open? Also, try passing the absolute pat to the file you want to open and see if that works

Comment: I tried absolute path before and it didn't work, now it does. Thank you very much!

Still has me wondering how this works and my method doesn't...

The os.path code doesn't give me any output/insight btw.

I want to give you credit for helping me.

Comment: My bad, I should have said `print(os.getcwd())`. Try with this and see if it's running where you think it is. The fact that the absolute path works makes me think your script is not running in the directory you think it is (although in that case the `os.chdir` method you tried should have fixed the issue, but maybe you have another problem in there as well?).